# Simply get the whole collection

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

Mongo 3.2
scalaVersion 2.11.7
activator-1.3.9

So I'm having trouble simply fetching a whole collection

I tried to use the documentation on the http://reactivemongo.org/ page and first connect

```
def connect() {
  // gets an instance of the driver
  // (creates an actor system)
  val driver = new MongoDriver
  val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))

  // Gets a reference to the database "plugin"
  val db = connection("plugin")

  // Gets a reference to the collection "acoll"
  // By default, you get a BSONCollection.
  val collection = db("acoll")
}
```

So far so good, I'm having 10 connections (as expected if I've read correctly).

Then I tried to modify what was on the documentation for "simple query", but came across IntelliJ saying that **cursor[BSONDocument]** is deprecated and I should use **cursor()** instead (which I did).

And I ended up with :

```
def getAll(collection: BSONCollection) = {
 val query = BSONDocument()
 val filter = BSONDocument(
   "_id" -> 1
 )
 val futureList: Future[List[BSONDocument]] =
   collection.
     find(query, filter).
     cursor().
     collect[List]()

 futureList.map { list =>
   list.foreach {
     doc => println(s"found document: ${BSONDocument pretty doc}")
   }
 }
}
```

Now in my controller I'm connecting with Db.connect (by the way, Db is an object Db {}, no idea if I should do this, kind of new in Scala, Mongodb and Play)

```
var collection = Db.connect()
println("Connected to db : " + collection)
var list = Db.getAll(collection)

...
```

Problem, Db.connect() doesn't seem to return a BSONCollection but a Unit

So I was wondering if you guys could give me a hint or something for a beginner like me ...

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but I'm confused even about the documentation as I cannot build a single piece of it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Db` ends with a `val` declaration.

If you have a look at the various Scala tutorials, you will see it means this function does return `Unit`.

If you want to return the value instead of assigning it locally, you have to remove the declaration, just having the last line as `db("acoll")`.

Then you function `getAll` suffers of the same misunderstanding.

```
futureList.map { list =>
  list.foreach {
    doc => println(s"found document: ${BSONDocument pretty doc}")
  } // foreach = Unit
} // so there's Future[Unit]
```

The DB resolution using `connection("plugin")` (aka `MongoConnection.apply`) is deprecated and discouraged.

It's recommanded you go deeper in the [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/index.html).